# Will the electric filed induced by Electromagnetic induction further induce magnetic field?

Tags: electromagnetism, electromagnetic-radiation, magnetic-fields, maxwell-equations

Just a thought experiment, if I move a magnet, the changing B will induce an E-field which is also time-variant. According to $\nabla\times H=\partial D/\partial t$ in Maxwell equation, the magnetic field is also induced by the time-variant E. And this process will continue to induce E and B field.

My questions are:

1. Does that mean the total magnet or electric field is a sum of all the induced B and E?
2. Why don't we consider the continued process in the questions of Electromagnetism?

(Basically, we consider the induced electromotive force but don't further consider the induced magnetic field)

Answer (score 1):

Indeed, changing magnetic field induced an electric field which in turn induces a magnetic field... which leads to the phenomenon known as *electromagnetic waves*. This is easy to see by using the relevant Maxwell equations together, [as shown here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electromagnetic_wave_equation#The_origin_of_the_electromagnetic_wave_equation).